# How to server side login using facebook and google using meteor?

Tags: facebook, meteor

my meteor app evolve to server side only now. so everything will be server side using rest api.

I need to login using social media on server side only.

this is example of payload :

```
{
"type" : "facebook",
"token" : "SOME_FB_TOKEN_HERE"
}
```

Google login :

```
{
"type" : "google",
"token" : "SOME_GOOGLE_TOKEN_HERE"
}
```

it will return :

```
{
"meteor_auth_token": "METEOR_AUTH_TOKEN_FOR_AUTHORIZATION"
}
```

how to do that in server side?

Answer (score 1):

I think it is possible only on client side. See https://docs.meteor.com/api/accounts.html#Meteor-loginWith 
where methods loginWithXXXXXXX work on client side only.
Maybe if you check how this methods work, you can create your self auth on server side.

Comment: Related: https://github.com/reactioncommerce/meteor-ddp-login (I forked it and changed it so I can login with my own OAuth2 server via DDP connection)

Comment: @Jankapunkt in example only loginWithPassword, is there any example using facebook and google?